# CSS | Footer with Logo

Tags: css, footer

Hey I just started to learn HTML at the Work. So, I started to make a Website for a Fake Company.I made a Navigation with Logo and a Side navigation.
But only with the Footer I got a Problem, cause its not in a row.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="footer">
 <ul class="footer">
  <li class="fuss"><a href="#">AGB</a></li>
  <li class="fuss"><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
    <div class="wortmarke">
     Caf&eacute; Villa Bernstein
      <p class="copyright">
        &copy; Caf&eacute; Villa Bernstein. All rights reserved.   
      </p>
    </div>
  <li class="fuss"><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
  <li class="fuss"><a href="#">Pressenews</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Footer */
ul.footer {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%; 
}

li.fuss {
  float: left;
  width: 10%
}

li.fuss a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wortmarke {
  color: #ffc995;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%; 
}

p.copyright {
 font-size: 40%;
 margin: -4%;
 color: white;
}
```

As you can See i have 4 Links (AGB, Impressum, Datenschutz and Pressenews), between Impressum and Datenschutz i want to add the Logo Text "Café Villa Bernstein" and below " © Café Villa Bernstein. All rights reserved.". The Problem is when i remove the "Logo Text" its all in a row.
When i add the "Logo Text" - the 2 Links "Datenschutz" and "Pressenews" jumps to the next row

[Here you can see my Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4k9w.png)

Now there is only one little thing i forgot to ask. I want a white border between the 2 Links ( AGB & Impressum and Datenschutz & Pressenews). When i add `border-right: 1px solid white` on the left side of Datenschutz there is missing a white border. So, i add `border left: 1px solid white`. But then the border between AGB & Impressum and Datenschutz & Pressenews is getting fat. My Question now is: How do i get between all elements the same border

[Fat Border between 2 Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx0rb.png)

Comment: I do not down vote as your newbie. Write more what's your problem in your footer and what you want

Comment: As you can See i have 4 Links (AGB, Impressum, Datenschutz and Pressenews), between Impressum and Datenschutz i want to add the Logo Text "Caf&eacute; Villa Bernstein" and below " &copy; Caf&eacute; Villa Bernstein. All rights reserved.". The Problem is when i remove the "Logo Text" its all in a row.
When i add the "Logo Text" - the 2 Links "Datenschutz" and "Pressenews" jumps to the next row

Comment: its not a good practice to use div inside `<ul>` either use `li` or use div instead of `ul` and create span inside div

Comment: Try adding float:left to .wortmarte class

Comment: @Bardo Thank you very much !!! Thats it, now i want to center the whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is:

```
li.fuss {
  float: left;
  width: 15%
}
```

Now the all the **li** and the middle **div** can 'cover' the whole footer (4*15% + 40% = 100% width).

I also added float:left in .wortmarke :

```
.wortmarke {
  color: #ffc995;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%; 
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

so that it will be floating with the rest of the **li**.

Finally, remove this block completely:

```
ul li:nth-child(4), ul li:nth-child(5) {
  float:right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

as it is unnecessary, not-responsive and does not support cross-browser compatibility

Comment: Thanks, this Version is for my use better than the other one :)

Now there is only one little thing i forgot to ask.
I want a white border between the 2 Links ( AGB & Impressum and Datenschutz & Pressenews). When i add "border-right: 1px solid white" on the left side of Datenschutz there is missing a white border. So, i add "border left: 1px solid white". But then the border between AGB & Impressum and Datenschutz & Pressenews is getting fat.

My Question now is: How do i get between all elements the same border

Comment: You should create css classes. It is generally recommended to use multiple classes in HTML elements so as to better describe what they do. For example:

.border-right{
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}


.border-left{
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

And use the first on AGB and the second on Datenschutz

Answer (score 0):

first of all to use DIV inside a list is not a good Idea. But I just corrected your code a little bit and will explain why it behaved like it did.

Your problem is that the div tag is `display: block;` by default and list is `display:inline;` which means that the div wants the whole line, thats why "Datenschutz and Pressenews" are moved away.

You need to change the display style to `inline-block;` and add a `float:right` to
"Datenschutz and Pressenews".

See working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmLL7boL/1/)

Comment: If you tell me how to Center the Middle im Happy :)

Comment: In your case you could adjust the width % of your li elements so the logo is centered, look the answer below. Adding a float to an element makes it automatically display:inline; so the answer below is great aswell.